# Javascript Toggle + Animate Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm having trouble with javascript animate. I've got one div that toggles to show a form, and another div that moves to the left when the form slides in. I'm trying to get the div to move back to the right when the form toggles to hide.

I've got it on JSFiddle. Any thoughts as to why it's not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/KWSvy/

Comment: example isn't working or displaying any html. Also no console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using assignments instead of comparisions. This is wrong:

```
if(direction = 'left')
if(direction = 'right')
```

It should be:

```
if(direction == 'left')
if(direction == 'right')
```

Also direction should be initialized:

```
var direction = 'left';
```

And in order to move the element back to its original position, you should animate margin back to 0 instead of +160.

http://jsfiddle.net/KWSvy/6/

Comment: I figured it was something easy like that, I just don't ever use javascript. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) Please note that it's recommended to mark answers that solved the problem in question as accepted (the little checkmark next to it), it's not only about reputation, but also helps others to pick the right information (assuming there are more answers), it's an indicator for other questioners and respondents that the question is solved, and others will be more encouraged to answer your questions when they see that it won't be for nothing.